# Stacked Tabs in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a lot of open tabs which requires scrolling back and forth.  I cannot figure out if sql developer allows you to "stack" or group tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Yes, you can group tabs.

Two ways, you can drag a tab off the main group, and drop over into a new one. Or you can right-click and say, 'New Doc Tab Group'